# Char array to byte array to readable String

Tags: java, arrays, ebcdic

I have a char array which I retrieved from WireShark which is:

```
char peer0_0[] = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0xf2, 0x5c, 0xc8, 0xd6, 0xe2, 
0xe3, 0xf1, 0xf9, 0xf2, 0x4b, 0xf1, 0xf6, 0xf8, 
0x4b, 0xf1, 0xf0, 0xf7, 0x4b, 0xf9, 0xf7, 0x40, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 
0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 
0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0xc1, 0xc2, 0xc3, 0xe2, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x5c, 0xc1, 0xe7, 
0xc9, 0xe2, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0xf0, 
0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 
0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0xc1, 0xe7, 0xc9, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe8, 0xe2, 0xe3, 
0xc5, 0xd4, 0xe2, 0xc4, 0xd5, 0xc2, 0xc8, 0xc4, 
0xc1, 0xe7, 0xc9, 0xe2, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0xf0, 0xf0, 
0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 
0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf3, 0xf0, 0xf1, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0xa6, 0xa2, 0xf7, 0x97, 
0x92, 0xf9, 0xf7, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 
0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x48, 0x53, 
0x47, 0x55, 0x46, 0x72, 0x74, 0x71, 0x62, 0x70, 
0x73, 0x70, 0x71, 0xc0, 0x46, 0x72, 0x74, 0x71, 
0x62, 0x70, 0x73, 0x70, 0x71, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 
0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 
0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 
0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 
0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 
0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 
0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 
0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

I have to convert this char array to a byte array.

With the successful conversion of the char array to byte array, I should be able to `new String(bytes, "Cp1047")` work since I have to convert the byte array to EDCDIC.

Comment: do we need post such long code ?

Comment: @LiuYan刘研: There's not much harm in it, and people usually go too much the other way (leaving out crucial information), so...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert: char array to byte array to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117989/convert-char-array-to-byte-array-to-string)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you shouldn't have that as a char array to start with. You say you retrieved it from Wireshark - but you haven't specified how.

Fundamentally what goes over the wire is binary data. There can be headers expressing an encoding to use when interpreting the data as text, but I would just keep it as binary data unless you *need* to treat it as text.

So change whatever's creating that char array to create a byte array instead. Don't convert *from* a char array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method to convert character array to byte array. This will help you.

```
 public byte[] convertCharArrayToByteArray(char[] peer0_0) {
  byte[] ba = new byte[peer0_0.length*2];
  int j = 0;
  byte mask = 0xff;

  for(int i = 0; i < peer0_0.length; ++i, j+=2) {
    byte upper8bits = (byte) ((peer0_0[i] >> (1<<3)) & mask);
    byte lower8bits = (byte)(peer0_0[i] & mask);
    ba[j] = upper8bits;
    ba[j+1] = lower8bits;
  }

  return ba;
}
```

Pass your character array as argument, you will get byte array. Then, you can convert byte array to EDCDIC.

Comment: I will check this ASAP. Can you please elaborate on how this works? This is the first time I'm encountering converting char[] to byte[] and it's also the first time I'm seeing operators such as >>, << and & which is used in your statement. I have little to zero knowledge regarding bits/bytes

Comment: I tried converting it to a String although nothing printed out.